Adding custom CRSs and coordinate transformations QGIS (modifying the CRS/CT catalog)
I am trying to add custom CRS and transformation definitions to the CRS/CT catalog in QGIS.
As far as I know, the qgis.db is meant to handle custom definitions. However, it does not contain a table for coordinate transformations. So, I have attempted to add a custom transformation from EPSG:4230 (ED 50 geographic) to EPSG:4326 (WGS84 geographic) to the srs.db, located here:
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.36.0\apps\qgis\resources
The transformation is a standard Geocentric translation (geog2D domain)  (Coordinate Operation  method 9603 in EPSG).
While I do see my custom transformation when I programmatically list all the transformations in srs.db from within QGIS, it does not appear in the list of available transformations in the "Coordinate Transforms" menu in the GUI when I select EPSG:4230 as the source CRS and EPSG:4326 as the target CRS.
I assumed that since PROJ is the geodetic engine which performs the transformation, the definition might need to be included in the PROJ database. Therefore, I attempted to add the same transformation to the proj.db found at the following location:
C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.36.0\share\proj
But it still not show up.
Is it possible to add rows to the srs.db and make them visible in the list of available transformations in QGIS? In case, how? Perhaps there are other databases that need to be modified as well?

QGIS version: 3.36.0
Operating system: Windows 10

